# Android Emulator Development

Tags: android-emulator

We are new to android and trying to develop a emulator…
Can I have any information about how to start uo to develop an emulator.
We were trying to search for some resources online but couldn’t find any for emulator development
Online stuff is all related to application development…Please suggest us some tutorials which would help us.

Comment: I don't understand, there is already an Android Emulator in the Android SDK. Why do you want to create a new one?

Comment: Are you trying to build an emulator that emulates the Android environment, or are you trying to build an emulator that runs in the Android environment that emulates something else?

Comment: We are trying to build an emulator that runs in Android and emulates something else. Its more like with new phones being launched, we want to build an emulator and try to emulate its functionalities as well as look and feel.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://discuz-android.blogspot.com/2008/01/about-google-android-emulator.html

The emulator is open source, you should be able to download the code and modify it any way you wish.

The link to the source is http://android.googlecode.com/files/android-emulator-m3-rc37.tar.bz2

I would seriously discourage trying to create an emulator from scratch. It would be nearly impossible without a large team with a lot of Android knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to develop a simulator from scratch. It requires a lot of effort and developers. You can take a look at existing simulator. I highly recommend you to try QEMU.